# Creating an n-nary expression

Tags: c#, .net

I have a sequence of N `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` that I want to convert into an N-Nary Expression which connects all my expressions into one using an operator N-1 times.

So for a collection of 4 expressions `{e1, e2, e3, e4}` and the operator `AND` I would get: `e1 AND e2 AND e3 AND e4`.

Since the operator is the same, I can create that expression by simply chaining together N-1 `BinaryExpressions`

```
Expression result = (((e1 AND e2) AND e3) AND e4);
```

But I'm thinking there may be an easier way of doing this. Basically something like

```
Expression.NNary(ExpressionType operator, IEnumerable<Expression> expressions)
```

Is there something like this already implemented or do I have to do it with `BinaryExpressions` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is the **reduce** function, known as `Aggregate` in LINQ. It reduces a sequence of values to a single value, like this:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int sum = numbers.Aggregate((acc, current) => acc + current, 0); // 10
```

How you're combining `acc` and `current` is up to you.

Comment: But how can this be used to combine expressions? This is what the question is about.

Comment: This is just a short/linq way of doing it with BinaryExpressions instead of looping through the collection and doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing implemented in the Framework, you have to use BinaryExpressions and concatenate those in a loop.